# VBA adding a carriage return at end of string when inserting value

Tags: vba, excel

I have the following code in my VBA module

```
Prinlen = Len(NewPrincipal)
If Prinlen > 25 Then
   NewPrincipal = Left(NewPrincipal, 25)
End If
ActiveSheet.Range(PrincipalRange) = NewPrincipal
```

For some reason it seems to be adding a carriage return at the end of the string when it is inserted, how doo I stop that from happening?

Comment: You may have misdiagnosed your problem. Your code is not inserting a `CR` at the end of the string.

Comment: Looking at the output there appears to be CR at the end.  A blank line after the name,  Even a Trim around the code makes no difference and the cell is large enough to prevent wrapping

Comment: If there is, it happened prior to the code you posted.

Comment: That is what has me so confused- there is nothing being posted to the cell prior to this point that would insert a CR.  Been experimenting, and with fewer characters (just tried 10), the same issue does not occur

Comment: How are you populating `NewPrincipal`, and how exactly are you testing for the CR at the end? If it's just visually, I suspect you're wrong. ;)

Comment: @MarcL What is returned if you insert a formula on your worksheet `=CODE(RIGHT(cell_ref,1))` where cell_ref is the cell containing this string of yours.

Comment: @MarcL Also, what happens to that extra line if you just widen the column?

Comment: Maybe you could post a screenshot which shows what the problem is.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same issue.  There is a carriage return and a line feed in my string, and I did not put there.  I initially suspected the issue was due to the 1,269 characters in the string.  The line break occurs at 1,023.  Your code is 141 characters--length is not the issue.

I resolved the problem by adding " & vbNewLine & _" before the line break.

The screenshots show what I did to troubleshoot:

Raw code from VBA Module

[image]

Raw code pasted to Notepad++
[image]

String copied from Immediate Window and pasted to Notepad++ (shows the CR and LF)
[image]

Addition of vbNewLine to raw code
[image]

Immediate Window Before and After
[image]